# str.length only returns a maximum of 20 (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, max

So basically I'm trying to get the length of an input of numbers. The following code runs but it only goes up to 20, after that it displays a length of 20 for any length of string that exceeds 20.

Can anyone help?

```
If index = 3 Then
    'BASE 2 to 10 CONVERSION SELECTED'
    output = ""
    Dim length As Integer = CStr(input).Length
    If length > 15 Then
        length = length - 3
    Else
        length = length - 1
    End If
    MsgBox(length)
End If
```

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your problem.  In your code you have "input", which is being converted to string.  What Type is "input" before the conversion?

Comment: 'input' is double datatype before conversion. I am trying to get the length of the input string since I am trying to iterate through a given number to convert into different codes. (i.e Binary code to Decimal code)

Comment: A variable declared as double can only hold 20 digits.  That is the problem.  Visual Studio should be giving you an error if you are trying to load more than 20 digits into a double.  If you suppress the error, then it will cut off your input to 20.   How are you getting the double (input)?  If it is user input to a textbox, then it is already a string, and you shouldn't declare it as a double.